# jquery autotab do not tab next row

Tags: jquery

When the textbox value lenght reaches max value, I want it to move to the next tab or 3 seconds later it moves to next tab. Here is my code:

```
$(".tab").keyup(function () {
    var get = $(this);
    if (get.val().length == this.maxLength) {
      get.next('tr .tab').focus();
    }
    else {
        setTimeout(function () {
            get.next('tr .tab').focus();
        }, 3000);
    }
});
```

When the cursor position in 1, it moves 2. But when the cursor in 2, it does not move 3.[image]Here is HTML codes:

```
<table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
    <tr>
      <td class="tds">Year / Number</td>
      <td><input name="year" type="text" class="inputbox tab" maxlength="4" style="width:25px;" /> / <input name="number" type="text" class="inputbox tab" maxlength="2" style="width:25px;"/></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="tds">Caption:</td>
      <td><input name="caption" type="text" class="inputbox tab" style="width:500px;" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="tds">Description:</td>
      <td><input name="desc" type="text" class="inputbox tab" style="width:500px;" /></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

How do I mange focusing if cursor is in 1 to 2, later if it is in 2 to 3 and later 3 to 4?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**[LIVE DEMO](http://jsbin.com/videjiqe/8/edit)**

```
var timeo,                      // Used for our timeout
    $TAB = $('.tab');           // Cache all your input elements for reuse           

$TAB.keyup(function () {

    clearTimeout(timeo);        // Clear timeout as you type

    var $el = $(this),          // cache element
        val = this.value,       // get value
        len = this.maxLength,   // get length
        i = $TAB.index( this ); // get the index of current one
                                // so we can increase it using +1      
    if (len != -1 && val.length >= len) {
        $TAB.eq(i+1).focus();
    }
    timeo = setTimeout(function () {
        $TAB.eq(i+1).focus();
    }, 3000);

});
```

**I'll try to explain my changes trough your issues:**

- your `input` elements are not all within the same `<TD>` parent so you cannot use `.next()` to get the.... well... *"not-next"*.
  Cache all your inputs in a `$TAB` variable. Now inside the `keyup` we need to keep track of the `index` of the currently used input, than increasing the value of `i = $TAB.index( this );` you can get the next indexed `input` out of our elements collection `$TAB` i.e:
  `$TAB.eq(i+1) // is the next one in collection`
- You did not cleared your `setTimeout` properly, therefore it would tick without waiting us to finish typing. I used for that case the `timeo` variable to store the `timeout` but also to allow us to clear it while typing in our fields.
- also, `if (len != -1` will make sure that an element has a `maxlength` attribute and `&& val.length >= len) {` will check for the entered value is bigger than the allowed maxlength.

Comment: @Roko I was following this answer and almost gave you a down vote after the third or fourth update... :-) Anyway, I just gave a +1 and would like to add that it would be rather easy to jump from the last field back to the first by checking the value of `i` against the size of `$TAB` and if `i`is the last `.tab` element then set `i` to `-1`. This would go just before the `$TAB.eq(i+1).focus();`